# How do I restart Unity

Tags: unity, compiz

I know about `unity --reset` command. 
But how can I simply restart Unity without resetting its profile?

Comment: What about unity --replace?

Comment: What's the equivalent for Unity 2D? http://askubuntu.com/questions/52179/how-do-i-restart-unity-2d

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I don't use Unity but given what I know of its mechanics, this should work:

```
unity
```

You'll want to stick that in a run box (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) rather than a terminal or it'll break when you exit the terminal.

If you want to run it from a terminal use:

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: That's correct. Although, logging out and back in works better in my experience (I'm using Unity as my main desktop environment at this point)

Comment: A good way to do it in a terminal, in case you want to see debug messages, is `setsid unity`. You can close the terminal when ever you like, but you'll still get the terminal output made by Unity.

Comment: If you want to run that in terminal without breaking it when you exit terminal, type: 'unity --replace &'

Comment: Just using `unity` will work as it is the identical command.

Comment: using unity --replace have a tiny catch, you have to launch the menu once then only the left bar will auto-hide after restarted

Comment: unity --replace has the most stupid description: "--replace         Run unity /!\ This is for compatibility with other desktop
                    interfaces and acts the same as running unity without". I don't understand why they haven't name the option --restart or --refresh, as this are self explanatory words. As --replace reminds me of something completely different.

Comment: @bioShark as it says, it's in line with other window decorators and compositors which do replace what's currently running. Eg `metacity --replace` displaces/replaces compiz just as `compiz --replace` displaces/replaces metacity as the compositor.

Comment: Ok, got the idea behind it. I am just not that used to this way of approaching statements. For me actually refresh would have made more sense :).

Comment: Brought the house down for me. -1

Comment: To logout quickly, you can use shortcut key `Alt+Printscreen+K` or command `kill -9 -1`.

Answer (score 7):

I found `killall -u USR1 -r -g unity*` (optionally, with -i for interactive) to be more effective than @Andrew's answer. My only problem with this vs `unity --replace` is that it will kill your session which `unity --replace` doesn't do. So, reserve this for when it is severely broken.

Answer (score 5):

`killall -USR1 unity` will restart it in an account (USR1) where you have not changed your killall defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that works is

```
pkill --signal USR1 unity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unity
```

which starts a new GUI connected to your terminal. however, if you run this over  SSH, ehm, this is probably not the best IDE, because your local desktop 'unity' instance is then bound to this terminal on your remote-desctop...

funny things occur, when you terminate [this](https://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/11/how-to-restart-ubuntu-unity-desktop/) session. Step by step your GUI will vanish and the only thing which remains under your control is the pointer of your mouse.

I found this post really helpful, which sumarises the commands mentioned in other answers.