# How do I restart Unity 2D

Tags: unity, unity-2d

As per [How do I restart Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31849/how-do-i-restart-unity)? But I guess `unity --replace` would start the 3D variant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

unity-2d has some of its own processes and some processes that derive from unity (unity-2d uses unity libraries).

You can find these processes with:

```
ps aux | grep unity
```

This yields these (see the right-most tokens in the above command output):

- unity-2d-launcher
- unity-2d-panel
- /usr/lib/unity-place-applications/unity-applications-daemon
- /usr/lib/unity-place-files/unity-files-daemon

Each of these can be individually stopped (and each will automatically restart) with:

```
sudo killall <process>
```

So to kill them all, list them all in the above command:

```
sudo killall unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel \
/usr/lib/unity-place-applications/unity-applications-daemon \
/usr/lib/unity-place-files/unity-files-daemon
```

Comment: This will kill the processes. Will they restart automatically?

Answer (score 7):

Since it won't let me post a comment to answer the question, it's necessary to add an answer:

> This will kill the processes. Will they restart automatically?

I can confirm that "killall unity-2d-panel" does in fact restart it, with no noticeable losses.  I haven't tried the other ones though.  (This command is necessary periodically if you're dealing with memory leaks like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/905854).