# How can I get rid of artifacts without logging out?

Tags: nautilus, visual-artifacts, drag-and-drop

So, I was dragging some files around in Nautilus and I wanted to cancel a drag.  So, I just hit escape.

Then I got this weird file icon floating always on top on my screen that I couldn't figure out how to get rid of.  Logging out and back in fixed it, but I'd rather not have to do that as I have this problem come up quite a bit.

I tried killing and restarting Nautilus (`kilall nautilus`), but that didn't fix it.

Here is a screenshot of the little visual artifact.

[image: File artifact from drag and drop]

Does anyone know a way to get rid of this by killing a process or something minor that?  I'd rather not have to close everything and log out every time.

Comment: Have you tried killing Nautilus with `killall nautilus` command? Just opening a new file browser window will start it again.

Comment: Yes.  The artifact is not from Nautilus.  I think it's part of the GNOME desktop.  I don't know how to restart my desktop without logging out and back in.  I'll edit that into my question.

Comment: You can try restarting either [Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31849/how-do-i-restart-unity) or [Gnome Shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455301/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-after-it-became-unresponsive-freeze), whichever you are using.

Comment: @Nattgew : How can I do that without logging out and killing all my other programs running?

Comment: I know the Gnome command only restarts the shell, all the programs stay open. Not sure about Unity.

Comment: @Nattgew : What is the Gnome command?  Just `gnome` at the terminal says command not found.

Comment: In Gnome shell, do Alt+F2 and then just `r` should restart the shell.